# Having Multiple Sort Methods

Tags: c#, sorting, console-application

I'm have a class with two methods, A QuickSort() and a ReverseArray(). When I pass in the array, it'll first call QuickSort(), and then ReverseArray(), however when it gets to ReverseArray(), it reverses the sorted array from QuickSort() instead of reversing the original Array that is made. What am I doing wrong? Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
    public class Program
    {
    private readonly int[] ProgramArray = new int[10] ;
    public Program(int[] array)
    {
       ProgramArray = array;
       QuickSort();
       ReverseArray();
    }

    public void QuickSort()
    {   
        var newarray = new int[10];
        newarray = ProgramArray;
        Array.Sort(newarray);
        Print(newarray, "QuickSort");
    }

    public void ReverseArray()
    {
        var newarray = new int[10];
        newarray = ProgramArray;
        Array.Reverse(newarray);
        Print(newarray, "Reversed");
    }

    public static void Print(int[] array, string methodname)
    {
        int[] newarray = array;
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0}: ", methodname));
        for (int i = 0; i < newarray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(newarray[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var array = new int[10] { 12, 24, 3, 44, 5, 16, 7, 34, 23, 34 };
        var program = new Program(array);

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array is a *reference* type. You are working on the *same* reference throughout your code base.

If you want a *copy* of the array, you need to copy it.

Here, `newarray` is not a *copy* of the array, but a copy of the *reference* to `ProgramArray`:

```
newarray = ProgramArray;
```

Use the [`Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k6f9ye6.aspx) method defined on `Array` in order to create copies:

```
Array.Copy(ProgramArray, newarray, ProgramArray.Length);
```

Also, I suggest reading about the differences between [value types and reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx).

Comment: Thx..I'm actually embarrassed that I never new that, I'm relatively familiar with c#, I just don't ever use arrays, I usually use List. Thanks for help.

Comment: Same thing for Lists and all other collection types. The vast majority of types in the .NET Framework libraries are reference types.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, arrays are reference types. In QuickSort, the line "newarray = ProgramArray" sets the newArray reference to the same instance as the ProgramArray. So Array.Sort is actually operating on ProgramArray. Similarly, in ReverseArray, Array.Reverse is also operating on ProgramArray. If you want to copy the array, use Clone().

Answer (score 1):

An Array is an object reference type, so the statement `newarray = ProgramArray;` causes `newArray` to reference the same array as `ProgramArray`. To avoid this, you'll have to copy the array.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code instead.   When assigning one array to another array you are not cloning or coping all elements.  You are assigning the memory address of the beginning part of the array.  In other words you are just assigning a reference variable to another array.  I.E. All of the array variables point to the same address space and thus you are modifying the same array even though you are using different variable names.

```
public class Program
{
    private readonly int[] ProgramArray = new int[10];
    public Program(int[] array)
    {
        ProgramArray = array;
        QuickSort();
        ReverseArray();
    }

    public void QuickSort()
    {
        var newarray = new int[10];
        newarray = (int[])ProgramArray.Clone();
        Array.Sort(newarray);
        Print(newarray, "QuickSort");
    }

    public void ReverseArray()
    {
        var newarray = new int[10];
        newarray = (int[])ProgramArray.Clone();
        Array.Reverse(newarray);
        Print(newarray, "Reversed");
    }

    public static void Print(int[] array, string methodname)
    {
        int[] newarray = array;
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0}: ", methodname));
        for (int i = 0; i < newarray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(newarray[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var array = new int[10] { 12, 24, 3, 44, 5, 16, 7, 34, 23, 34 };
        Print(array, "Original Array");
        var program = new Program(array);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what the others told you about reference types, I suggest you to pass the array to be sorted as parameter to the sorting methods, instead of using a global array `ProgramArray`. This makes easier to understand the flow of information.

```
public void QuickSort(int[] array)
{
    // Easiest way to get a copy of the array
    var newArray = (int[])array.Clone();
    ...
}

public void ReverseArray(int[] array)
{
    var newArray = (int[])array.Clone();
    ...
}

public Program(int[] array)
{      
    QuickSort(array);
    ReverseArray(array);
}
```

Comment: Yep I actually had it like this when I started, but changed it thinking I was doing something wrong with copying the array(which i was obviously), but I changed it back to this, your right this is cleaner. Thanks.